# How do I update/change a Page's location to reflect the page as a Service Area Business(no street etc)?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I know this is possible via the user interface: [image: UI]

I have a page that I manage and want to know how I can do this via the Graph API. Sending an empty string for `street` key keeps returning `"(#200) Permissions error"`. :(

Looks like location field is a mandatory field and needs to have at least street & zip code.

[image: Graph API documentation]

Comment: If it's possible through the user interface (and it's a one time setting meaning once it's set, you won't touch it anymore), why do you want to use the Graph API ?

Comment: The graph api documentation (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/page/#Updating) says that you can update the location, assuming you have permission to do so.
Have you tried changing the street to any other value? Does that still return error 200?

Comment: @rak007 We cannot assume that it's a one time setting.

Comment: @simonalexander2005 Yes I did try to send in empty value to the street. It errors out with 200 permission error. 

Sending state ISO in the street field can be a hack but  would seem weird in the Facebook page though. GMB has an option to provide option to mention if the business is a Service Area Business. Looking for something on similar lines.

Answer (score 0):

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/places/web/search

Two ways:

1. Service Area = f ( center, categories, distance)
2. Service Area = f ( q, categories, distance) //this is your answer

q means the name of the location. If you want to search Little Rock city, provide "Little Rock" there. Based on distance value you can increase/decrease your Service Area.

Comment: @Uddav Gautam it's for Facebook GraphAPI.

Comment: @Anath, I meant to say this.